# Forecasting based on revenue and advertisement

Tags: forecasting, games

How to forecast revenue based on previous revenue and advertisement budget?

This is how the data looks like, see full [data on google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XFzmpKef9Br8MKP_82kbbp-I-rKnNkM61j-gwxbd_7I/edit?usp=sharing) or even better on [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zoS7tLuJIaBn8lERsNO3KFONnzFmHNFK?usp=sharing).
[image]
[image]

EDIT:

- With my limited knowledge in Excel I know to forecast based on a single parameter (here: previous revenue), I want to forecast based on two parameters: previous revenue AND advertisement budget.
- Based on the answer of @Stephan Kolassa, I opened a [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zoS7tLuJIaBn8lERsNO3KFONnzFmHNFK?usp=sharing) and tried to make a forecast that take into account lagged variables, lets assume that advertisement budget affect for 12 months.

Is it ok to ask from an answer to post a Colab notebook with a solution?

---

Details:

- This data is for an indie game made by my friend.
- Advertisements produce revenue which is spread upon several years, this is because must player churn after several months but some players play the game several years.
- In the forecast I placed 500$ per month for the next 13 months, this is of course a decision parameter that I (the friend) can play with if he see that higher advertisement will produce better results.

Comment: You seem to be setting aside most facts, starting from the idea that Excel offers forecasting based only on previous revenue. Who told you that? In fact, Excel offers various different kinds of forecasting and even when those require a single data input, that says nothing  about what ent into that input.

There might well but by no means 'should' be a relationship between advertising and revenue.

Comment: Hi @RobbieGoodwin, I started by saying "From the little that I know", no one told me that, this is what I could produce while playing with the Excel.  If you can demonstrate how to do it via Excel, Sheets or Colab I would be very thankful

Comment: Are all advertising dollars going to the same advertising channels?

Comment: They don't, but for the sake of the question, they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple approach would be a regression model. Since the effect of an expenditure may only appear a few months later, you would need to work with lagged variables, or using sums of historical expenditures to predict the next month's revenue. The problem is that you will likely not have enough data to estimate the effects precisely, especially if you have to choose the lag structure. So I would recommend you use a simple method that works, and live with some remaining uncertainty. [This may be helpful.](https://dfep.netlify.app/sec-causal)